# Symfony Security AuthenticationListener not calling attemptAuthentication method

Tags: php, security, symfony

**UPDATE: I did end up getting this to work, but it was a long hard slog. I can't say why the below code doesn't work, but as a reference, I did benefit a lot from looking at this github ldap symfony security implementation. https://github.com/BorisMorel/LdapBundle**

I'm implementing a custom authentication provider and I'm stuck. I have a listener that extends AbstractAuthenticationListener. It has a constructor and implements a attemptAuthentication method. When stepping through my code in a debugger, the constructor for the listener is called, but the attemptAuthentication is never called.

Here's the listener in question.

```
namespace AppBundle\Security\Firewall;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\AuthenticationManagerInterface;
//use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\securityContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ListenerInterface;
use AppBundle\Security\Authentication\Token\LdapUserToken;
use AppBundle\Security\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Util\SecureRandom;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\AbstractAuthenticationListener;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Session\SessionAuthenticationStrategyInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\HttpUtils;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;

    class LdapListener extends AbstractAuthenticationListener
    {
      public function __construct(SecurityContextInterface $securityContext, AuthenticationManagerInterface $authenticationManager,
          SessionAuthenticationStrategyInterface $sessionStrategy, HttpUtils $httpUtils,
          $providerKey, AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface $successHandler,
          AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface $failureHandler, array $options = array(),
          LoggerInterface $logger, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
      {

        parent::__construct($securityContext, $authenticationManager, $sessionStrategy, $httpUtils, $providerKey, $successHandler, $failureHandler, $options, $logger);
      }

        protected function attemptAuthentication(Request $request)
        {
            $username = $request->get('username');
            $password = $request->get('password');
            if (!(strlen($username) > 0) || !(strlen($password) > 0)) {
              return;
            }

            $token = new LdapUserToken();
            $token->setUser($username);

            $generator = new SecureRandom();
            $token->digest   = md5($generator->nextBytes(32));
            $token->nonce    = $generator->nextBytes(32);
            $token->created  = time();
            $token->setPassword($password);

            try {
                $authToken = $this->authenticationManager->authenticate($token);
                $this->securityContext->setToken($authToken);

                return $authToken;
            } catch (AuthenticationException $failed) {
              return;
            }
        }
    }
```

And here's my firewall definition.

```
firewalls:
        login_firewall:
          pattern: ^/app/login$
          anonymous: ~
        ldap_secured:
          pattern: ^/
          ldap: true
          form_login:
            check_path: app_security_login_check
            login_path: app_security_login_path
```

And here's my services.yml for this security stuff.

```
services: 
  security.authentication.success_handler:
    class: AppBundle\Security\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandler
    arguments: ["@security.http_utils", {}]
  security.authentication.failure_handler:
    class: AppBundle\Security\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandler
    arguments: ["@http_kernel", "@security.http_utils", {}, "@logger"]
  ldap.security.user.provider:
    class: AppBundle\Security\User\LdapUserProvider
    arguments: ["@service_container"]
  ldap.security.authentication.provider:
    class: AppBundle\Security\Authentication\Provider\LdapProvider
    arguments: ["@ldap.security.user.provider", "@service_container"]
  ldap.security.authentication.listener:
    class: AppBundle\Security\Firewall\LdapListener
    arguments: 
      - @security.context
      - @security.authentication.manager
      - @security.authentication.session_strategy
      - @security.http_utils
      - 'ldap'
      - @security.authentication.success_handler
      - @security.authentication.failure_handler
      - []
      - @logger
      - @ldap.security.user.provider
  ldap:
    class: AppBundle\Utils\LdapConnector
    arguments: ["@service_container"]
```

**Update: After stepping through the Symfony security code, in AbstractAuthenticationListener.php it is calling the UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener for some reason.**

**Update 2: I think my issue is with the form_login in the config yaml file. That's using the authentication stuff provided by symfony and not my ldap security stuff. Here's my security.yml file now, but I get an error about check_path, login_path and provider not being valid options.**

```
    security:
      encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
      role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
      providers:
        ldap_provider:
          id: ldap.security.user.provider
      firewalls:
        login_firewall:
          pattern: ^/app/login$
          anonymous: ~
        secured_area:
          pattern: ^/
          ldap_secure:
            check_path: app_security_login_check
            login_path: app_security_login_path
            provider: ldap_provider
        dev:
          pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
          security: false
      access_control:
        - { path: ^/app/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Here's my factory.

```
// src/AppBundle/DependencyInjection/Security/Factory/LdapFactory.php
namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection\Security\Factory;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\DefinitionDecorator;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\NodeDefinition;
use Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\DependencyInjection\Security\Factory\SecurityFactoryInterface;

class LdapFactory implements SecurityFactoryInterface
{
  public function create(ContainerBuilder $container, $id, $config, $userProvider, $defaultEntryPoint)
  {
    $providerId = 'security.authentication.provider.ldap.'.$id;
    $container
    ->setDefinition($providerId, new DefinitionDecorator('ldap.security.authentication.provider'))
    ->replaceArgument(0, new Reference($userProvider))
    ;

    $listenerId = 'security.authentication.listener.ldap.'.$id;
    $listener = $container->setDefinition($listenerId, new DefinitionDecorator('ldap.security.authentication.listener'));

    return array($providerId, $listenerId, $defaultEntryPoint);
  }

  public function getPosition()
  {
    return 'pre_auth';
  }

  public function getKey()
  {
    return 'ldap_secure';
  }

  public function addConfiguration(NodeDefinition $node)
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: If you got it working would you mind updating with the code that worked? I've been slogging through all this security crud too. Looking at other's code that does not work isn't too helpful :)

Comment: @DinoAmino I would, but I'll be honest with you, I got so spun around in circles figuring this out, I don't really know what worked and what didn't. I would focus on this implementation https://github.com/BorisMorel/LdapBundle I basically did what he did.